# Resource id #5: MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
//Sessions starten
session_start();
//Include stuff
include('conf.php');
//'Shortcuts' maken
$sname = $site['name'];
$shost = $site['host'];
$shostb = $site['hostb'];
//Verbinding maken met DB
$link = mysql_connect($database['host'], $database['username'], $database['password']) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database['db'],$link) or die(mysql_error());
//Gegevens uit db halen
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page['title'] = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = $_GET[page]");
}
else{
    $page['title'] = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = 'index.php'");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $sname;?>•<?php echo $page['title']?></title>
```

Does somebody know why this doesn't work? My DB structure is:

> ### page     |title
>
> index.php|index

Sorry but I can't get this clear. The var **dump** of `$page['title'] = resource(5)` of type (mysql result). How can I fix this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) returns a resource, you need to use [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (or similar, e.g. [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)) on the resource to get the title value.

For example:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = 'index.php'");
$page = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
 
// $page['title'] now contains the value (assuming there's an index.php page in the DB).
```

Warning: your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` encourages potential bad practices. It's better (and more efficient too) to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, though in this case where you only need to get 1 field from 1 row, I would use `mysql_result`.

Comment: It work now! Thanks all for the fast answer. (I used mysql_result($result,0 here. =))

Answer (score 0):

This is resourc id returned by `mysql_query` Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` on the resource to get the title value.

Do below changes :

```
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = $_GET[page]");
    }
    else{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = 'index.php'");
    }
   $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $page['title'] =$row['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function like `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_result()` to get the actual data.

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[page]) . "'");
     $page['title'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'title');
}
else{
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = 'index.php'");
     $page['title'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes in **4 years late** but mysql_* is deprecated. You should use mysqli_* or PDO functions instead